# Global existence of IVP on $\mathbb R$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, metric-spaces

> Suppose $f(t, x)\in C^1(\mathbb R^2)$ and satisfies $|f(t, x) |\leq 1+|x|$ for any $(t, x) \in\mathbb R^2$. Then prove that the IVP $x'(t) =f(t, x)$ and $x(0)=0$ has a solution defined on whole $\mathbb R$.

I tried to find local solutions by restricting $f$ to rectangles. But it seems like it couldn't be guaranteed that the solution even exists on the whole interval. Another idea is to try to prove it by approximating $f$ uniformly by polynomials. I'm sure how to make it work. I'd like to get hints on how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the extensibility theorem - [see document, Theorem 1.20](http://www.calvin.edu/~tmk5/research/ClassNotes512.pdf) and its corollary about maximal solutions to prove what you want. Or mimic the proof to your particular example.